# Microsoft Teams get Bearer Token

Tags: jwt, authorization, token, microsoft-teams

I want to get authorization token of Microsoft Teams with username and password of a user of my tenant. I have credentials, but I cannot understand how to get token from Microsoft Teams API.
I followed HTTP requests from browser to see what Teams is doing in the background, I saw some GET/POST/PUT on beta endpoint but I'm lost about authorization token (I just saw it in "Authorization" header at a certain point, and if I take this string I can call some APIs. I'm aware also of skypetoken, but can't clearly see the difference between).

What I want to achieve is to write a Python script that does authentication, get token, manages Teams account (create a new team, channel, invite members, ... all without registering an app on Azure and grant it permissions - I'm not an administrator of my tenant, and without downloading Microsoft SDK).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best way definitely is with an Azure Application registration. If you're not able to work with your own tenant admins, then it could be possible to do this in a separate tenant (e.g. a free [Developer tenant](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program)). This will only work if your organization policies allow users (e.g. you) to authenticate to external applications (in this mode, it doesn't require an admin to log you in, but it requires that your tenant not BLOCK external applications).

Comment: So you mean that there is no possibility to achieve same results without a registered app?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. Microsoft strongly wants to avoid this kind of authentication, with passwords lying around, and in addition it breaks if you have (which you should!) MFA on your account. Instead the application approach lets you use tokens, in your case refresh tokens.